# How to send request parameters of dictionary using Freddy Framework in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I am using Freddy Framework for parsing the Json. I understood how to send String,Int,Bool. but now I am getting confuse how to send the request parameters for array and dictionary using Freddy. Below is the sample json format

```
"paymentMethods": [. - For Array
"paypal"
],

"contactInfo": {
"email": "consumerUSA@paypal.com",
"phone": "XXX-456-XXXX",
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Smith"
},
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending JSON data in request:

1. First you need to encode your object into json data. You can find the documentation on [JSON encoding using Freddy][1] here
   [1]: https://github.com/bignerdranch/Freddy#jsonencodable-serializing-other-objects .

   `let objectAsJSON: JSON = myObject.toJSON()`

   `let jsonData: Data = try objectAsJSON.serialize()`
2. Then you need to set the JSON data to your *request.HTTPBody*. Like this

   `request.HTTPBody = jsonData`